# How to use data from one factory in another factory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm trying to test my app so that when a user votes for a certain kind of food, both the count of user.votes goes up as well as food.votes.  As of now I can't that to happen, and I'm not sure if I've written my tests wrong or have set up a factory that will not make it possible for the tests to pass. It works when I test manually in the console, so I know that it does function, but the tests do not agree.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
factory :vote do |f|
    f.user_id user
    f.food_id food
end
end
```

---

```
def create
@vote = Vote.new(vote_params)

if @vote.save
    flash[:notice] = "Thanks for voting!"
else
    flash[:notice] = "Something went wrong"
end
end
```

---

```
before(:each) do
  @user = create(:user)
  sign_in(@user)
  @food = create(:food)
end

describe "POST #create" do
context "with valid attributes" do
  it "creates a new vote" do
    vote_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:vote)
    expect { post :create, params: { vote: vote_params } }.to change(Vote, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "Updates @user vote count" do
    vote_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:vote)
    expect { post :create, params: { vote: vote_params } }.to change(@user.votes, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "Updates @food vote count" do
    vote_params = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:vote)
    expect { post :create, params: { vote: vote_params } }.to change(@food.votes, :count).by(1)
  end
end
end
```

---

```
Failures:

1) VotesController POST #create with valid attributes Updates @user vote count
 Failure/Error: expect { post :create, params: { vote: vote_params } }.to  change(@user.votes, :count).by(1)
   expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/controllers/votes_controller_spec.rb:27:in `block (4 levels) in <top  (required)>'

2) VotesController POST #create with valid attributes Updates @food vote count
 Failure/Error: expect { post :create, params: { vote: vote_params } }.to change(@food.votes, :count).by(1)
   expected #count to have changed by 1, but was changed by 0
 # ./spec/controllers/votes_controller_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

 Finished in 2.99 seconds (files took 4.66 seconds to load)
 36 examples, 2 failures

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/controllers/votes_controller_spec.rb:25 # VotesController POST     #create with valid attributes Updates @user vote count
rspec ./spec/controllers/votes_controller_spec.rb:30 # VotesController POST #create with valid attributes Updates @food vote count
```

Comment: Could plausibly be that you would need a `@user.reload` for the count to update... You can test if this is the case by trying something like: `expect { post :create, params: { vote: vote_params } }.to change{ Vote.where(:user_id => @user.id).count }.by(1)` to make sure it always has fresh data

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. I tried it out but unfortunately it is still saying it did not change from 0 to 1

Comment: ok... so not that. Now it's plausible that there's an odd validation-error on the vote, or the user is not properly signed in or that kind of silly thing. Can you check each of those things? Does `"creates a new vote"` pass or do all of them fail? Can you show us the error messages for the failure? (put it int he original question rather than in comments so the code-formatting isn't too dreadful) :)

Comment: Okay I edited my post. The creates a new vote test does indeed pass. The user is signed in as well

Comment: ok, lets have a look at the vote that got created then... in your "creates a new vote" can you put a final line that's something like `puts "vote: #{Vote.last.inspect} for user: #{@user.id} and food: #{@food.id} and params: #{vote_params.inspect}"` and then show us what is output on the screen when you run that test? That should give us a good overview of everything that's going into the test.

Comment: When I add that line, I end get #<Vote id: 1, created_at: "2016-10-31 01:21:06", updated_at: "2016-10-31 01:21:06", user_id: 0, food_id: 0> for user: 26 and food: 15>. I also then tried directly setting my vote factory to have a user_id of 26 and a food_id of 15 but that did not work either

Answer (score 0):

Ok, confident enough to take a guess. The issue, I think, is that `vote_params` is coming from a factory (probably with hard-coded values for user_id/food_id) - but not the real `@user` and `@food` that you are testing against. You need to put these values into your `vote_params` can I suggest something like the following:

```
context "with valid attributes" do
  # Set vote-params from factory, then merge in the @user/@food ids
  let(:vote_params) { FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:vote).merge(:user_id => @user.id, :vote_id => @vote.id) }

  it "creates a new vote" do
    expect { post :create, params: { vote: vote_params } }.to change(Vote, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "Updates @user vote count" do
    expect { post :create, params: { vote: vote_params } }.to change(@user.votes, :count).by(1)
  end

  it "Updates @food vote count" do
    expect { post :create, params: { vote: vote_params } }.to change(@food.votes, :count).by(1)
  end
end
```

Comment: hmm okay when I try this I end up with:  NoMethodError:
       undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass

Comment: okay I got it to pass! I used your suggestion, but I had to change the .merge part to: (:user_id => @user, :food_id => @food)  Thank you for your help!